# Is it best practice to have a file only of "includes/requires"?

Tags: php, mvc

I have 5-10 files on one server that all catch XMLRPC-PHP requests.  There's about 20 lines of `require_once` in each one that are all the same.  It'd make life simpler for me to create a separate file that only has the `requires` and `require` that in my XMLRPC files.  Is this best practice, or does it open up issues that I don't know about?

Comment: Have you considered consolidating the includes into a single file, perhaps as part of your build step? The performance gain can be worth it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done that before and it did save some effort, but got it fiddly as I didn't always need every single file and sometimes needed a few more. If you always need those and only those, then I think it's a good plan.

However, there are alternatives if you have control of the file hierarchy and are not using third party libraries e.g. using php's [__autoload()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) function to have the files automatically included when you try to instantiate the class. I'd tend to prefer this if at all possible as it needs a lot less maintenance.

Answer (score 3):

Basically any set of identical code in multiple places should be consolidated.  As long as you're sure the exact same set of includes are required in each place I would put them together in one file.  The performance difference (if any) is negligible and maintainability is more important.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would definitely make your life simpler. As mentioned by others before, I would recommend using the autoloading mechanism.

There is an implementation in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), I found it pretty useful. It might look something like this:

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');

// Or, using an anonymous function as of PHP 5.3.0
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});
```

If you are on PHP 5.3, also consider using namespaces. It's actually even easier to have a good structure and a simple autoloader implemented by default:

```
spl_autoload_extensions(".php"); // comma-separated list
spl_autoload_register();
```

However, I remember a bug there. Usually I have a 'bootstrap' file, with this autoloader:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    if(file_exists('./lib/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php')) {
        require_once './lib/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
    }
});
```

Using this mechanism, you have a folder structure that mimics your namespace structure. With this approach, you have a good structure, and do not need to care about including your libraries and other classes.